# Comment notifications if @ is added later

Tags: support

This is a niggling doubt I've had for some time now, so thought might as well get it cleared up. I often add comments and forget to @ notify someone. If I edit the comment and add the @username later, will the user still be notified or are notifications sent out only when the comment is first posted? Asking because many times it has seemed as if notifications weren't sent out after comment editing.

Comment: Stepping forward as a guinea pig. Once a second person comments, you can test this with us.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Second comment. Edited it one minute after to add the @.

Comment: I was properly pinged. Image uploading doesn't work right now, so no screenshot. Edited to ping @TFM

Comment: Properly pinged here as well.

Comment: Karan, are you using autocompletion for @-usernames? There are some rules governing when pings are sent (e.g. two users with same user name prefix).

Comment: @DanielBeck: Sometimes when I edit I just type the first few letters (>=3) of the name, but most times I do use auto-completion. (Edited to add your name.)

Comment: Still works. Maybe people just don't bother to reply directly to your comments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments to this question, editing `@` into a comment does notify the target user.

([status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) would seem to make sense here, but this isn't a bug report `:)`.).

Comment: Yeah, seems to be working fine now. Perhaps it was some sort of intermittent glitch or even a misunderstanding. Anyway, answered and closed.